# How strong is the adhesion between UHMWPE Fiber and Epoxy Resin?

Tags: materials, composite, composite-resin, adhesive, epoxy

How strong is the adhesion between Ultra High Molecular Weight Polyethylene(UHMWPE) Fiber and Epoxy Resin normally? If we take the UHMWPE fiber sheet as it is without subjecting it to any chemical or plasma treatment (for improved surface bonding between UHMWPE fiber and Epoxy resin), can a laminate be formed through compression molding? Will there be any issues or  loss of mechanical properties like impact resistance for UHMWPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a chemist or material scientist, but it is my experience that reliable adhesion to a smooth Polyethylene surface is nearly impossible even with "plastic" rated epoxy.

However where it is a fiber sheet, the epoxy, even with zero surface adhesion, will mechanically hold each fiber it encapsulates. I can not speak to what mechanical properties will result as it would be highly dependent on the fiber geometry. Some online research and testing is probably your best route.

Comment: Agreed. Eveb with some adhesion promoters it's still not reliable in my experience.